# Typescript Conditional rendering, Type 'undefined' is not Assignable to type CompanyStatsProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can someone help me debug an issue with typescript,

The issue is I have some a functional component with props set as a specific type.

```
export interface AppState {
    companyStats?: CompanyStatsProps;
    errorMessage?: string;
}
```

Company Stats are props for child component. It's rendered only if companyStats is available.

Initial State of the application is

```
state = { companyStats: undefined, errorMessage: undefined };



render() {
        if (this.state.companyStats) {
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <NavBar onSearch={this.handleCompanySearch} />
                    <DashBoard companyStats={this.state.companyStats}/>
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        }
```

So the issue is although I have handled the undefined issue with an if statement but typescript doesn't know that it think's companyStats can be undefined, and it throws an error.

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'CompanyStatsProps'.
```

I am new to react and  I don't know how to handle this conditional rendering.

PS: CompanyStats (state) is updated upon user Search and an API call, didn't include that or other statements in the code coz I thought they won't be useful for debugging purpose. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `CompanyStatsProps`? Is it a class or an interface?

Comment: it's an interface

Comment: Tags describe the *content* of the question. If the question is not about Angular, then using the [angular] tag is inappropriate. Simple as that. I don't know enough about ReactJS to know if the question is actually about that. If it is, then the tag is fine. If it's just a Typescript *language* issue, then you also do not need the [reactjs] tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** Write this instead

```
export interface AppState {
    companyStats?: CompanyStatsProps | undefined;
    errorMessage?: string;
}
```

**Long Answer:** When you have set the type of **companyStats** as **CompanyStatsProps**, you are telling typescript that **companyStats** will always be defined. It can never be undefined. Therefore, when you are assigning **undefined** to it, it is showing an error. So by writing

```
companyStats?: CompanyStatsProps | undefined;
```

you are telling typescript that it can be either undefined or CompanyStatsProps.

Comment: NO, it won't work writing companyStats?:  CompnayStatsProp is equivalent to CompnayStatsProp | undefined, the "?" Symbol represents optional. The issue is in child component it's not optional so if in parent component I set it to "?" TS thinks it can be undefined, but it can't be as I have handled same with IF statement but TS doesn't know that and throws an  error

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the props of `CompanyStatsProps` interface, if you wanna set `companyStats` prop as `undefined` like below. For example purpose, I am assuming `CompanyStatsProp` has two properties `id` and `name`

`state = { companyStats: { id: undefined, name: undefined }, errorMessage: undefined };`

Comment: I have defined the state in such a way that a property will be of type X or will be undefined if the property is undefined the component will NOT  be rendered.  if while initializing instead of setting companyStats as undefined I set it as companyStats: { id: undefined, name: undefined }  I will have to add more checks. If I add more props in future i.e companyEmployesDetails which will be updated by an API call made by a user search, I will have to add a check for these props as well.